# what are the eigenvalues in orthgonal matrix, How to explain?

Tags: linear-algebra

what are the possible eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix?

I got the answer key which says its 1 and -1 but it doesn't explain well

Comment: What's **your** definition of "orthogonal matrix"?

Comment: the transpose is equal to its inverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another definition of an orthogonal matrix (from MathWorld) is that $A^T = A^{-1}$ (A is square) meaning $A^T A = I$

Recall that the transpose of a square matrix has the same eigenvalues as the original matrix (Meaning $A \vec v = \lambda \vec v = A^T \vec v$)

Taking our eigenvalue equation $A\vec v = \lambda \vec v$ and multiplying by $A^T$ on both sides then gives

$A^T A \vec v =\lambda A^T \vec v \implies  \vec v = \lambda^2 \vec v$

Which is true if and only if $\lambda = \pm 1$

Comment: i have trouble understanding the last step how do you get lambda times A^T,-> lambda^2?

Comment: Since $A^T$ and $A$ share eigenvalues and eigenvectors then $A^T \vec v = \lambda \vec v$

Comment: Why can't $\lambda=0$?

Comment: Since orthogonal matrices are invertible all of their eigenvalues must be nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that if $U$ is an orthogonal matrix, we then have $\Vert Ux \Vert_2 = \Vert x \Vert_2$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$.

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $U$ and let $v$ be an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$. We then have
$$U v = \lambda v \implies \Vert Uv \Vert_2 = \vert \lambda \vert \Vert v \Vert_2$$
But since $U$ is orthogonal, we have $\Vert Uv \Vert_2 = \Vert v \Vert_2$. Hence, this gives us $\vert \lambda \vert  = 1$.

Hence, any real eigenvalue of an orthogonal matrix has to be either $+1$ or $-1$. It is important to note that the orthogonal matrix can have complex eigenvalues.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh yes. I tried to stretch the argument a bit too far.

Comment: what does the 2 mean? square?

Comment: $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ means the $2$ norm of a vector.

Comment: so it basically means the length

Comment: @statstudent Yes.

Answer (score 0):

By your definition, $U^t=U\;$ for an orthogonal matrix $\;U\;$ , but since a matrix and its transpose have the same eigenvalues (why?), we get that if $\;v\;$ is an eigenvector of $\;U\;$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\;\lambda\;$ ,then

$$Uv=\lambda v\implies v=vI=U^tUv=U^t(\lambda v)=\lambda U^tv=\lambda^2v\implies \lambda^2=1$$

and we're done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach. Recalling the fact

> if $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda^{-1}$ is the eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$,

we have

$$ \langle Ax,x \rangle =  \langle x, A^T x \rangle = \langle x, A^{-1} x \rangle $$

$$ \implies \langle \lambda x,x \rangle  = \langle x, \frac{1}{\lambda} x \rangle $$

$$ \implies \lambda \langle  x,x \rangle  =\frac{1}{\bar \lambda} \langle x,  x \rangle $$

$$ |\lambda|^2 = 1 .$$